# new to android understanding listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I was going through the vogella's tutorial and came across this code:

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
super.onAttach(activity);
if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
} else {
throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+ " must implemenet MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
}
}
```

I am not sure what it does. Here is what i do know:

i know that onAttach is called when the fragment has been associated with the activity.
i know that OnItemSelectedListener is an interface
I know that it checks if the activity correctly implements this interface, but not sure what the following code does :  listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity

all i understand is that it type casts it to become OnItemSelectedListener... but what else does it do ?

Comment: What do you mean? What are you asking?

Comment: You know it checks that activity implements the `OnItemSelectedListener`, what do you mean by "not sure how"? Are you wondering how the instanceof code works?

Comment: im not sure what listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity does, all i understand is that it type casts it to become OnItemSelectedListener... but what else does it do ?

Comment: No, that's it, you cast it to that type (the interface type in this case). What do you mean with "what else". Should something else happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface is specified on the class declaration. An Activity class can extend Activity and implement the `OnItemSelectedListener`.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener { }
```

The code only knows that it is of type `Activity` when `onAttach` is called, but you *want* an `OnItemSelectedListener`, so you need to cast activity. Thats what the `listener = (OnItemSelectedListener)activity` code does, it casts the instance activity. So in order to avoid a generic `ClassCastException`, a check is performed first and if activity is not of the correct type, an exception with a more specific error text is thrown.

There's nothing particuarly special going on, the cast enables you to call methods defined in that interface. You don't get any new instances or something, listener and activity is the same object.

Comment: The Exception is not _avoided_ but will be thrown manually with a more helpful message.

Comment: thnxs for the answer, however i need some clarification: what exactly does casting the activity object to onItemSelectedListener do ? It seems to do nothing. I can't find anywhere listener does anything significant..

Comment: @user3134565 `Activity` and `OnItemSelectedListener` does not necessarily declare the same members, so the cast enables you to call methods declared in the interface using listener.

Comment: ok i get it now, the activity needed to be forced to follow the rules of OnItemSelectedListener so that the method inside of it can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually useless outside the tutorial project you were reading on vogella. This code in particular checks if the `FragmentActivity` trying to be associated with the parent activity implements `OnItemSelectedListener` and the reason it is doing so is because if an action that doesn't implement all the properties of `OnItemSelectedListener` is attached to the `AdapterView` it will raise an exception because the Dalvik Virtual machine won't be able to handle the request to execute that particular action properly.
The following line:

```
litener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
```

converts the object of type `FragmentActivity` to an object of type `OnItemSelectedListener` and copies that value to the `listener` variable which is most likely an attribute of the class that implements the `onAttach(Activity activity)` method in question.